# Did Doc sleep with Clara the night of the festival?

Tags: back-to-the-future, back-to-the-future-iii

In *Back to the Future Part III*, after the festival, Clara is showing Doc craters on the Moon through her telescope. Afterwards they start talking about their favorite writer, Jules Verne. Then they kiss and the scene ends.

The next morning Marty realizes that Doc is missing. Did he spend the night with Clara at her house? If yes, then it appears unseemly for a woman in the 19th century to sleep with a man on the first date, doesn't it? She probably risked her reputation as a teacher.

Comment: "If yes then it seems obscenely for a woman in the 19th century to sleep with a man on the first date, doesn't it? She probably risked her reputation as a teacher." Well, yes and yes, I think: but lot's of people did it anyway.

Comment: I saw the title and thought this was about Doctor Who :-/

Comment: The part about it being unseemly or surprising to you is actually unneeded. It's a valid question either way.

Comment: @Zabeus I think the "unseemly" bit is to question whether it would be realistic for such a casual relationship to result in sex given the mores of that period in history, not to suggest any value judgement of the author.  Kind of like, "Wouldn't it be unreasonable to build a rocket-sled with colored smoke bombs in that period?"  And to Adamant's point, people have been doing it forever under far more restrictive mores than that!  (The sex, not the smoke bombs.  Nobody does the smoke bombs.)

Answer (score 7):

**The film implies that they didn't have sex but the novelisation implies that they did.**

The next time we see the characters together in the film, she accuses him of telling a tall tale because he thinks it will allow him to take advantage of her.

> "...*because you know I'm partial to the writings of Jules Verne you concocted those mendacities in order to take advantage of me!*".

The same conversation in the [official novelisation](https://backtothefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_Part_III_novelization) however (based largely on the shooting script) is that she thinks he's doing it so that he can take advantage of her ***again*.**

> ‘I understand that,’ Clara continued rapidly, ‘because you know I’m
>   partial to the writings of Jules Verne, you concocted those
>   mendacities in the expectation that you could take advantage of me **one
>   last time.’**

You may make your own judgements accordingly.